# Is there a horizontal scroll bar in python's idle?

Tags: python, python-idle

I am using IDLE to learn Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

The Vertical scroll bar works fine but I cannot find
a way to activate the Horizontal scroll bar.

Is there a horizontal scroll bar in Python's IDLE?

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, you can hold shift and scroll with the mouse to move horizontally in IDLE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Horizontal Scroll Bars for IDLE

from http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/26878/
(**not my code**, found it on this site)
It is dated Wed, 08 Mar 2000

Works for Python 2.6 but I can't get to work in 2.7.  I get an error saying that the file is open some where. For me, the file he is talking about is located in:C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\idlelib  It will be different if you do not have the ArcMap program which comes with python and installs it for you.

> I finally got around to adding horizontal scroll bars to the IDLE
>   editor window to help when you get those LONG lines of code.  They
>   changes are rather mionor (4 new lines of code) and were made in the
>   EditorWindow.py module.  To make the changes in IDLE, open
>   EditorWindow.py and perform a search for 'vbar' which is in the
>   EditorWindow class, `__init__` method. Add those lines that have `###`
>   appended to them and VOILA you have it. Unfortunately, the scrollbar
>   appears BELOW the row and column information in IDLE 0.5 (*sigh*).
>
> ```
>     self.vbar = vbar = Scrollbar(top, name='vbar')
>     self.hbar = hbar = Scrollbar(top, orient=HORIZONTAL, name='hbar') ###
>     ...
>     vbar['command'] = text.yview
>     vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
>     hbar['command'] = text.xview        ###
>     hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)      ###
>
>     text['yscrollcommand'] = vbar.set
>     text['xscrollcommand'] = hbar.set   ###
> ```
>
> Hope this is helpful.
>
> Jonathan Polley
>
> jwpolley at collins.rockwell.com

Comment: Works like a charm in Python 3.4.1!

Comment: I've added a version for Pytrhon 3.6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755273/1264516

Answer (score 2):

No.  IDLE does not have horizontal scrollbars for two reasons:

1. Its text editor has few features.
2. You shouldn't be writing long lines of code.  See the [Maximum Line Length](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) section of the PEP 8 Style Guide for Python Code

Comment: Good to know the about the style guide and the recommendation.

Comment: I was trying to fit both brower and IDLE on same screen to type in code from tutorials. Find typing works better for learning purposes than cut and paste. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Sometimes people just don't want IDLE to use up 50+% of screen real estate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using IDLE 2.7.3, Windows 7, and I can scroll horizontally by holding down the center mouse button/scroll wheel, and "dragging" around the cursor like that.

Comment: This also "works" in IDLE 3.11.3 on W10, but it acts like the "hand" tool of PDF viewers (except it's too fast) instead of the scroll-drag behaviour of a browser. I personally find this solution unusable.

Answer (score 2):

I may not be a Python expert/guru yet but this question is a user-experience / usability question more than anything.  Some might say "Yeah, PEP 8 style guide... blah blah blah" but if I have the IDLE window a certain size (let's say small width), there's no reason I as a user shouldn't be able to scroll.  It's simply poor user-experience as a result of poor design.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, the text scrolls horizontally based on where the insertion point or selection is.

Comment: Ok, so I should use cursor, home and end keys to move horizontally?

Comment: Yes, or you can use the mouse by dragging. And of course you can just make the window wider.

Answer (score 1):

See http://bugs.python.org/issue1207613

The [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) project provides an extension for displaying a horizontal scroll bar in IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

**Horizontal Scroll Bars for IDLE, for Python 3.6.**

Thanks to Amber and his/her answer, I've found the way to make it work for Python 3.6.

You have to make some changes in the same class `EditorWindow`, but now it's located in a different module: "editor.py" at %python%\Lib\idlelib\ (win).

First you have to make a change in the same method `__init__`. And then  create a new method `handle_xview` for the same class.

Here is the code, you have to add the lines that end with `###`:

```
    self.vbar = vbar = Scrollbar(text_frame, name='vbar')
    self.hbar = hbar = Scrollbar(text_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, name='hbar') ###
    ...
    vbar['command'] = self.handle_yview
    vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    text['yscrollcommand'] = vbar.set

    hbar['command'] = self.handle_xview ###
    hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)      ###
    text['xscrollcommand'] = hbar.set   ###
```

And the method:

```
...
def handle_yview(self, event, *args):
...
...
def handle_xview(self, event, *args):      ###
    "Handle Horizontal scrollbar."         ###
    self.text.xview(event, *args)          ###
    return 'break'                         ###
...
```

Comment: For Python 3.8.0, you now need to change the `hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)` line to `hbar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=NSEW)`

Answer (score 0):

No, because Python PEPs [emphasize](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), that line length *should* be 79 symbols at most. Most of the people violates this of course.