# How to Horizontally Resize Text Layout in Python Shell?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, python-idle

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows and my output which is a table containing 15 rows needs more than the width of my entire screen to be displayed properly.

I used `pandas.set_option('display.width', 1920)` to get this working. However, word wrap occurs. I want the Python Shell to get a Horizontal Scroll Bar. Checked under configure IDLE and couldn't find it. It just needs to be like the simple option of word wrap we get with Notepad.

EDIT: I've already tried that method explained in the question marked possible duplicate. That doesn't create a working toolbar. The text is still wrapped. The toolbar graphic is present but it is greyed out and has no functionality.

Comment: are you talking about IDLE or are you talking about a windows console in which python.exe is running?

Comment: I'm talking about Python Shell. I mentioned about checking 'Configure IDLE' option in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a horizontal scroll bar in python's idle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301071/is-there-a-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-pythons-idle)

Comment: @Boud It's not working. Edited the question to include that update.

Comment: It's mentioned it doesn't work in 2.7.

Comment: Yeah. So this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: IDLE's Windows can be manually resized, just like the console windows that Python normally runs in.  At least on Windows, the console also does not have horizontal scrollbars.  IDLE has an option to set the initial height and width of Shell and Editor windows.  This take effect immediately for newly opened windows.  It cannot, however, be set programmatically.

Comment: The question of adding horizontal scrollbars to IDLE windows has been controversial.  Some have opposed them because they would supposedly encourage long code lines.  IDLE is intended for development of programs, not running them.  But yes, they must be run as part of development.  I am considering reopening the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://bugs.python.org/issue1207613) is the 11 year old opened issue showing IDLE doesn't support horizontal scroll bar. IDLEX as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301071/is-there-a-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-pythons-idle) provides extensions to IDLE and workaround that, apparently not working for Python 2.7.

Comment: IDLEX doesn't work. I'll just reduce the font size to 7 and squint. Python IDLE clearly not up to the mark even after 11 years.

Comment: That's why generally one doesn't use IDLE for data science related projects but other tools like IPython, Jupyter, etc. Your question is a duplicate but you seem to accept that idea.